# EF Code First Many-to-Many Relationship with ASP.NET Identity Table at one Side

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to accomplish many-to-many relationship using code-first EF with ASP.NET Identity table at one side. The join table is not generated in the DB, though. What am I missing? Here are my model classes:

AppUser.cs:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public AppUser()
    {
        Notes = new HashSet<Note>();
    }

    public DateTime? LastSuccessfulLoginDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

and

Note.cs:

```
public class Note
{
    public Note() {

        NoteAssignedToUsers = new HashSet<AppUser>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int NoteID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int FileID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Importance? Importance { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH.mm}")]
    public DateTime AddedOn { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CreatorID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FileID")]
    public virtual OAFile OAFile { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatorID")]
    public virtual AppUser CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AppUser> NoteAssignedToUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your dbcontext you can configure:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Entity<Note>()
                .HasMany<AppUser>(s => s.NoteAssignedToUsers )
                .WithMany(c => c.Notes)
                .Map(cs =>
                        {
                            cs.MapLeftKey("AppUserId");
                            cs.MapRightKey("NoteId");
                            cs.ToTable("AppUsersNotes");
                        });

}
```

Comment: Thank you Dei, but this is Fluent API. How can I configure that in Code First?

Comment: Both are code first you can use code first with the fluent api or the data annotations

Comment: Yes, I know, I meant data annotations. I would like to know why EF did not create the join table in the first place without the need of Fluent API.